# Can I use Square Reader output for my own usages?

Tags: android, ios, payment, stripe-payments, square

I want to build a payment device such Square Reader, but for checking that is it feasible in my country I decided to work on Square to analyse the feedbacks, yet, I have two question:

1. Can I use Square device and just write new software for interpreting
   the data?
2. Is square reader's output encrypted?

Any other ideas are welcome from anyone, thanks.

Comment: If you are going to handle payments ypu will have to comply with the [PCI](https://www.pcicomplianceguide.org/pci-faqs-2/) (Payment Card Industry) requirements including encryption. PCI applies to ANY organization or merchant, regardless of size or number of transactions, that accepts, transmits or stores any cardholder data.

Comment: Square readers are encrypted, there are a number of other readers but you face PCI issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Square's readers with custom Android and iOS applications using the [Square Register API](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/articles/register-api-overview/). That way you could accept payments with your custom app, but not have to worry about PCI compliance and other regulations.